# "Правильное" возобновление EventListener'а в Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firestore

**Общее описание ситуации:**

Есть проект, работающий с `Firestore` в реальном времени. Изначально логика получения данных в нем была такова: я получал все данные, а потом вешал `EventListener` для обновления уже существующего списка. В какой-то момент я решил отказаться от такого принципа в пользу одного `EventListener`'a из-за конфликтов. Сейчас логика выглядит так:

Fragment:

```
public class ActionsFragment extends Fragment implements ActionsFragmentBase {

    private Unbinder unbinder;
    private ActionsPresenter presenter;
    private ActionsRecyclerAdapter actionsAdapter;
    private int state;
    private int type;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        presenter = new ActionsPresenter(this);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_actions, container, false);

        type = this.getArguments().getInt("type");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        presenter.notifyFragmentStarted(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        presenter.removeRegistration();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        presenter.removeRegistration();
    }

    public void handleListUpdate(DocumentChange.Type type, int newIndex, int oldIndex, Action action) {
        if (actionsAdapter != null) {
            switch (type) {
                case ADDED:
                    actionsAdapter.addItem(newIndex, action);
                    break;
                case MODIFIED:
                    actionsAdapter.updateItem(oldIndex, newIndex, action);
                    break;
                case REMOVED:
                    actionsAdapter.removeItem(oldIndex);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isListEmpty() {
        return actionsAdapter == null || actionsAdapter.getItemCount() == 0;
    }

    public boolean isAdapterExists() {
        return actionsAdapter != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        actionsAdapter = null;
        unbinder.unbind();
        presenter.destroy();
    }
}
```

Presenter

```
public class ActionsPresenter {
    private ActionsFragmentBase fragment;
    private ActionsModel model;

    private Query actionsQuery;
    private ListenerRegistration actionsRegistration;

    public ActionsPresenter(ActionsFragmentBase fragment){
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.model = new ActionsModel();
    }

    public void notifyFragmentStarted(int type) {
        switch (type) {
            /* Выбор Query в зависимости от type */
        }

        setRegistration(type);
    }

    private void notifyViewCreated(int state) {
        fragment.showRequiredViews();

        switch (state) {
            /* Показ необходимых View в зависимости от состояния */
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setRegistration(int type) {
        actionsRegistration = actionsQuery.addSnapshotListener((documentSnapshots, e) -> {
            if (e == null) {
                for (DocumentChange dc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot doc = dc.getDocument();
                    Action action;

                    /* Получение объекта Action в зависимости от type*/

                    if (fragment != null) {
                        if (!fragment.isAdapterExists() && fragment.isListEmpty()) {
                            fragment.setupLayouts(true, true);
                            notifyViewCreated(Globals.FragmentState.STATE_CONTENT);
                        }

                        fragment.handleListUpdate(dc.getType(), dc.getNewIndex(), dc.getOldIndex(), action);
                    }
                }

                if (fragment != null && fragment.isListEmpty()) {
                    fragment.setupLayouts(true, false);
                    notifyViewCreated(Globals.FragmentState.STATE_NO_DATA);
                }
            } else {
                if (fragment != null) {
                    fragment.setupLayouts(false, false);
                    notifyViewCreated(Globals.FragmentState.STATE_NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void removeRegistration() {
        actionsRegistration.remove();
    }

    public void destroy() {
        removeRegistration();
        fragment = null;
        model = null;
    }
}
```

В коде я опустил все второстепенные моменты, которые не оказывают большого влияния на проблему.

Изначально я "проворонил" этот момент и метода `onResume()` у меня не было, а `presenter.notifyFragmentStarted(type);` вызывалось еще в `onCreateView()`. Тогда я понял, что после паузы `EventListener` переставал работать. Таким образом, я пришел к текущему состоянию.

**Описание проблемы:**

В текущий момент вновь вылезла "моя любимая" проблема: после возобновления фрагмента данные дублируются, т.е. в старый список вновь добавляются те же самые элементы. Конечно, на ум мне сразу приехала стая велосипедов с охапкой костылей в багажнике, но мне кажется, что я что-то упускаю. Что-то настолько очевидное, что я не вижу его прямо перед своим носом. Не может же быть такого, что дубли должны отбираться вручную.

Надеюсь, что моя писанина хоть немного объяснила суть проблемы. Заранее благодарю за предоставленные ответы.

**UPD**

Порылся в официальным примерах и нашел, что каждый раз при отключении слушателя они обнуляют список элементов в `RecyclerView`. Попробовал - конечно, работает, но тогда каждый раз при возобновлении фрагмента список будет прогружаться заново, хотя я бы не хотел еще очищать, а работать с тем, который уже был загружен. Как временный workaround, пойдет, наверное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в коде перед тем как выполнять действия с документами в коллекции (actionsRegistration = actionsQuery), вызывать процедуру очистки вашего списка с данными, так:

list.clear();

Comment: Ну тут 2 пункта. 1 - список у меня нигде не хранится, а динамически обновляется внутри адаптера. 2 - очистки и повторного обновления списка я бы и хотел избежать. Однако, этот вариант все-таки работает, что я и описал в "UPD". Возмжно, и стоит закрыть этот вопрос с подобным решением.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно усложнить код, чтобы понять какой элемент у вас обновился внутри списка, если не хотите изменять список.

Comment: Наверное, приму Ваш ответ, т.к. формулировка вопроса была: "“Правильное” возобновление EventListener'а в Firestore". По факту, очищение списка является наиболее верным решением в данном случае, давая результат при минимальных затратах.